I have formation movement for multiple agents but cannot rotate said formation
My navigation system is built around Aron Granberg's A* Pathfinder Project (asset found in the Unity asset store or just "webbing" around). Its syntax is very similar to how Unity's Navmesh navigation reads and writes.
The code examples below correctly navigate agents to predetermined positions inside a List<T>. The
agents are fed a target Vector3 based on their rank in another list dedicated to currently selected units. The failure of my logic is that the entire formation will not rotate as I have it so far. The individuals all rotate and path independently, but the alignment of positions remains fixed in the same direction with every call to these functions.
TL;DR: this moves units into a tactical arrangement but does not rotate the formation as a whole. I want to rotate the whole formation.
public class ReadyUnit
    {
        public PlayerControl player { get; set; }
        public int rank { get; set; }
    }

    public class Formation : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Formation Instance { get; private set; }

        enum order
        {
            loose,
            column,
            circle,
            vanguard,
            firingLine
        }

        [Header("All player characters share the same SINGLE PathOrganizer in the scene.")]
        [SerializeField] order arrangement = order.loose;
        [Range(1, 15)][SerializeField] int rank;
        PathOrganizer organizer;
        ReadyUnit unit;
        public static List<ReadyUnit> readyUnitList = new List<ReadyUnit>();
        int currentRank;
        

        private void Awake()
        {
            unit = new ReadyUnit { player = gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerControl>(), rank = currentRank };
        }

        private void Start()
        {
            if (IsLeader())
            {
                unit.rank = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                unit.rank = rank;
            }

            /* There should only be ONE instance of PathOrganizer in the scene */
            organizer = FindFirstObjectByType<PathOrganizer>();
            Selector.Instance.UnitSelectedEvent += OnUnitSelected;
        }

        void OnUnitSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Selector.Instance.GetSelectedPlayersList().Contains(gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerControl>()) && 
                readyUnitList.Contains(unit) == false)
            {
                readyUnitList.Add(unit);
            }

            if (Selector.Instance.GetSelectedPlayersList().Contains(gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerControl>()) == false &&
                readyUnitList.Contains(unit))
            {
                readyUnitList.Remove(unit);
            }

            if (Selector.Instance.GetSelectedUnit() == gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerControl>())
            {
                unit.rank = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                unit.rank = rank;
            }

            SortUnitsByRank();
        }

        void SortUnitsByRank()
        {
            readyUnitList.Sort((leftHand, rightHand) => leftHand.rank.CompareTo(rightHand.rank));
        }

        public void FallInStep(Vector3 point)
        {
            if (point == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (readyUnitList == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            SortUnitsByRank();
            MoveToPosition(point);
        }

        void MoveToPosition(Vector3 point)
        {
            switch (arrangement)
            {
                case order.loose:
                    LooseArrangement(point);
                    break;
                case order.column:
                    ColumnArrangement(point);
                    break;
                case order.circle:
                    CircleArrangement(point);
                    break;
                case order.vanguard:
                    VanguardArrangement(point);
                    break;
                case order.firingLine:
                    FiringLine(point); 
                    break;
            }
        }

        bool IsLeader()
        {
            return Selector.Instance.GetSelectedUnit() == gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerControl>();
        }

        void LooseArrangement(Vector3 point)
        { 
            float offset = Random.Range(-2f, 2f);

            List<Vector3> values = new List<Vector3>
            {
                point,
                point + new Vector3(offset, 0, offset),
                point + new Vector3(offset, 0, offset),
                point + new Vector3(offset, 0, offset),
                point + new Vector3(offset, 0, offset),
                point + new Vector3(offset, 0, offset),
                point + new Vector3(offset, 0, offset),
                point + new Vector3(offset, 0, offset),
                point + new Vector3(offset, 0, offset),
                point + new Vector3(offset, 0, offset),
                point + new Vector3(offset, 0, offset),
                point + new Vector3(offset, 0, offset)
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++) 
            {
                PlayerControl player = readyUnitList[i].player;
                player.GetComponent<MovementManager>().MoveToDestination(values[i]);
            }
        }

        void ColumnArrangement(Vector3 point)
        {
            List<Vector3> values = new List<Vector3>()
            {
                point,
                point + new Vector3(2f, 0, 0),
                point + new Vector3(0, 0, -2f),
                point + new Vector3(2f, 0, -2f),
                point + new Vector3(0, 0, -4f),
                point + new Vector3(2f, 0, -4f),
                point + new Vector3(0, 0, -6f),
                point + new Vector3(2f, 0, -6f),
                point + new Vector3(0, 0, -8f),
                point + new Vector3(2f, 0, -8f),
                point + new Vector3(0, 0, -10f),
                point + new Vector3(2f, 0, -10f),
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < readyUnitList.Count; i++)
            {
                PlayerControl player = readyUnitList[i].player;
                organizer.transform.position = point;
                organizer.AssignPosition(values[i]);
                
                player.GetComponent<MovementManager>().MoveToDestination(organizer.ConfirmedPosition());
            }
        }

        void CircleArrangement(Vector3 point) 
        {
            float diameter = 2.5f;

            for (int i = 0; i < readyUnitList.Count; i++)
            {
                float angle = (float)(i * (2f * Math.PI / readyUnitList.Count));
                float cos = (float)Math.Cos(angle) * diameter;
                float sin = (float)Math.Sin(angle) * diameter;

                point = new Vector3(point.x + cos, point.y, point.z + sin);
                PlayerControl player = readyUnitList[i].player;
                player.GetComponent<MovementManager>().MoveToDestination(point);
            }
        }

        void VanguardArrangement(Vector3 point)
        {
            List<Vector3> values = new List<Vector3>()
            {
                point,
                point + new Vector3(1f, 0, -1f),
                point + new Vector3(-1f, 0, -1f),
                point + new Vector3(2f, 0, -2f),
                point + new Vector3(-2f, 0, -2f),
                point + new Vector3(3f, 0, -3f),
                point + new Vector3(-3f, 0, -3f),
                point + new Vector3(4f, 0, -4f),
                point + new Vector3(-4f, 0, -4f),
                point + new Vector3(5f, 0, -5f),
                point + new Vector3(-5f, 0, -5f),
                point + new Vector3(0, 0, -1f),
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < readyUnitList.Count; i++)
            {
                PlayerControl player = readyUnitList[i].player;
                organizer.transform.position = point;
                organizer.AssignPosition(values[i]);

                player.GetComponent<MovementManager>().MoveToDestination(organizer.ConfirmedPosition());
            }
        }

        void FiringLine(Vector3 point)
        {
            List<Vector3> values = new List<Vector3>()
            {
                point,
                point + new Vector3(1f, 0, 0),
                point + new Vector3(-1f, 0, 0),
                point + new Vector3(2f, 0, 0),
                point + new Vector3(-2f, 0, 0),
                point + new Vector3(3f, 0, 0),
                point + new Vector3(-3f, 0, 0),
                point + new Vector3(4f, 0, 0),
                point + new Vector3(-4f, 0, 0),
                point + new Vector3(5f, 0, 0),
                point + new Vector3(-5f, 0, 0),
                point + new Vector3(6f, 0, 0),
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
            {
                PlayerControl player = readyUnitList[i].player;
                player.GetComponent<MovementManager>().MoveToDestination(values[i]);
            }
        }
    }


This reaches across the aisle to:
public class PathOrganizer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject destinationMarker = null;
    IAstarAI agent;
    MovementManager movement;
    Vector3 callback = Vector3.zero;

    private void Awake()
    {
        agent = GetComponent<IAstarAI>();
        GetComponent<MovementManager>();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        transform.position = Selector.Instance.GetSelectedUnit().transform.position;
        movement.ReachDestinationEvent += OnDestinationReached;
    }

    void OnDestinationReached(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Transform child in gameObject.transform)
        {
            Destroy(child.gameObject);
        }
    }

    public void ClearDestinationMarkers()
    {
        foreach(Transform child in gameObject.transform)
        {
            Destroy(child.gameObject);
        }
    }

    public void AssignPosition(Vector3 point)
    {
        agent.destination = point;
        GameObject waypoint = Instantiate(destinationMarker, point, Quaternion.identity);
        waypoint.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform, true);    
        waypoint.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(90, 0, 0);
        callback = point;
    }

    public Vector3 ConfirmedPosition()
    {
        return callback;
    }

    public void SteerFormation()
    {
        agent.destination = Input.mousePosition;
    }
}

The variable Vector3 callback shoots the vector back to a MovementManager.cs, that finalizes the move. That part also works just dandy. That last method (SteerFormation) is where I snag. What you see there is just a place holder command until I can finally score a "W" against this challenge. I have trying more complicated rotation logic involving find heading and magnitude or aligning it with the camera's field of view. The previous failures and the one above do indeed turn the container GameObject (PathOrganizer) but the positions within are never altered.
The problem as I see it is that these positions that are instantiated (via destinationMarker) reflect global positioning and are really no more than stamps on the ground where they are. I want these markers to ride inside of the PathOrganizer like it is a bus and the agents are dogs chasing the bus. In theory, if I steer the bus the whole flock follows in kind. I have investigated similar queries but haven't found (or perhaps did not understand) a satisfying solution.

From a "logical" point of view, all my "evolutions" start from a known formation; e.g. "line". If the formation is indeterminate, it has to first "assemble". For each formation, I have (pre)determined what the "end points" and facing angle should be for each unit. I then script each one individually. If it's "shortest route", they run at their own duration. If they need to "arrive" at the same time, they are all set to the same duration. For more "refined" evolutions, I add intermediate points; e.g. go left x before going forward Y; to avoid obstacles or "bumping". (this is all "generated")

Hmm, I like it. Routine it out so everybody finds their spot in the boat (so to speak), then hit the boat marching orders. As I am just reading this, I haven't put any attempt toward this effort yet. This does offer a keen hypothesis.

Units have a "fixed" position in line "posting order" (my term). There is a left wing and a right wing. There is a "center" (the colors). In column, it is "left in front", or, right in front. (I added icons to show the wings and colors). "Kill" a wing or color party, and the formation (group) is "shattered". No more worrying about evolutions. :0)
